# Export contract address and ABI from Ethereum Remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, remix

For a number of reasons, Ethereum Remix is great for developing in Solidity.  However, I need to integrate what I develop there into some other Web3 front end stuff.  So after each time I deploy a smart contract in Remix I have to copy and paste the contracts address as well as the ABI into another IDE so it can interact with the Web3 frontend.

Is there some sort of way to do the step of copying the contract address and ABI from Remix into a text file on my local system? I couldn't find a Remix API.  Was wondering if anyone has another idea.